# Using an ORM with IOC fro transaction management .NET

Tags: c#, testing, orm, inversion-of-control

I have worked with Spring and Hibernate in Java, and had a great experience using in for Testing. Using DI and aided by all the components provided the SpringFramework I created powerfull tests without worrying about my connection to my data sources. I there any kind of framework integration in .NET? In Spring you can use:

```
public class FooBarUnitTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
```

Is there any already existing "analogy" to this in .NET?

Comment: maybe these will help ;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx
http://www.netcel.com/Resources/Insights/Blog/Unit-Testing-C-Pt1-Basics/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'yes' - there are equivalent frameworks to implement the same ideas in the Java frameworks you mention. In C# .NET, you can pick and choose:

IoC (Spring) equivalents

- [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/)
- [AutoFac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac)
- [ServiceStack Func](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container)
- many others...

ORM Equivalents (Hibernate)

- [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/)
- [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Micro-Orms (lightweight) are getting more popular

- [ServiceStack OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)
- [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Testing

- [xUnit.net](https://xunit.codeplex.com/)
- [NUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nunit/)
- MS Test

Many of the same software development principles and practices apply.